# dynamic filtering with three collection_selects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, filter

I have a list of all users that I want other users to be able to filter based on three umbrella attributes for User:

1. Industries (the one the user works in now in addition to any the
   user has worked in previously)
2. Companies (the one the user works at
   now in addition to any past ones)
3. Schools (any that the user has
   attended).

These attributes are being pulled in from LinkedIn so that each industry/company/school is its own data field (current/past one/past two/etc.) in my user model.

Here's part of my schema to give a picture of my User model:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    ...
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    ...
    t.string   "current_company"
    t.string   "past_company_one"
    t.string   "past_company_three"
    ...
    t.string   "current_industry"
    t.string   "past_industry_one"
    t.string   "past_industry_two"
    t.string   "past_industry_three"
    ...
    t.string   "school_zero_name"
    t.string   "school_one_name"
   ...
end
```

I want to have three collection_select fields (industry/company/school) that a user can use to *dynamically* filter the list of users returned to them. It would look and function very much like the three select/filter fields here: https://angel.co/startups

Not sure exactly where to start on this and could really use some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider having the 3 attribute representations on separate models. So you'd end up having Company, Industry and School models for storing a user's past and current company, industry and school entries.

That way, each company/school/industry can have more attributes such as for what period of time was the user working/schooling. With that, it will be as easy as saying user.companies or user.schools once you have set up the model associations between the 3 models with the User model. You could also add a field in Company and Industry models to indicate which company or industry the user is currently working in to distinguish between the past companies/industries the user has worked in.

Something like this:

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :companies
  has_one  :current_company, :class_name => "Company", :conditions => { :current => true }
end

class Company < AR::Base
  # == Schema attributes
  #
  #  id               :integer(4)      not null, primary key
  #  name             :integer(4)
  #  user_id          :integer(4)
  #  current          :boolean         :default => false, :null => false
  #  start_date       :date
  #  end_date         :date

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: thank you. did you mean belongs_to :user instead of belongs_to :company?

Comment: also, once these new models are set up, i'd still have to set up the dynamic filtering (filter a returned set of users in industry x by company y). would appreciate being pointed to any good resources

Comment: that was a typo, I updated the answer. For the filters try and use named scopes. Ryan Bates has [a nice screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope/) on the topic. Good luck.